# How to create transparent png image using TPNGObject (PNGimage unit)

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I'm trying to create an icon (16x16) with semitransparent (50%) white background and with nontransparent white stripe. This PNG image will latter be used as tray icon (graph) in my application.

Visualization

[image]

I really can't figure out how TPNGObject allows user manipulation of an Alpha channel. Canvas.Pixel only support RGB. I was hoping for something like canvas.AlphaPixel ...

Comment: Delphi 7 does not have its own native PNG support, so which 3rd party `TPNGObject` are using actually using?  [This one](http://proger.i-forge.net/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D1%8C%D1%8E%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80/Delphi/[20120225]%20Useful%20Delphi%20packages/) has an `AlphaScanline` property, just make sure to call the `CreateAlpha()` method first.

Comment: Enter `[delphi] TPNGObject` in the searchbox above. I suspect that some of the 44 items listed, will answer your question.

Comment: A TColor is a 4 byte integer. Similarly the pixel setter SetPixel calls the SetPixel api which takes a COLORREF, which is a DWORD. I'm not claiming that this should work with .Pixels but I don't see anything that would eat the highest byte in the process.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau
Correct. I'm using TPNGObject from your link. Thank you.